# Range selector input fields can't edit after hide() show()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, highcharts

I've found some issue with selectors fields. They can't be changed after using jQuery hide() and show() methods on chart container. Is this a bug, or I've do something wrong?

Here is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/hal9000pro/jL3SX/

```
$(function(){
    $('#stock-mails-diagram').hide().
        highcharts('StockChart', {
            rangeSelector : {
                inputDateFormat:"%Y-%m-%d",
                inputEditDateFormat:"%Y-%m-%d"
            },

            title : {
                text : 'Emails sent per day'
            },
            series : [
            {
                name : 'mails sent',
                type: 'area',
                step: 'true',
                data : mails
            }],
            plotOptions:{
                area:{
                    dataLabels:{
                        enabled:false
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    $('#stock-mails-diagram').show();
});
```

Comment: Don't generate chart in a hidden container, it may cause such problems, see [FAQ](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/frequently-asked-questions#jquery-ui-tab).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally highcharts should be created in hidden div, so you can use workaround like here http://www.highcharts.com/docs/frequently-asked-questions

Comment: Perhaps you meant that highcharts should be created in visible but not hidden container. Anyway thanks for pointing on this thought. I've deal with it in this way http://jsfiddle.net/hal9000pro/jL3SX/10/